# different while loop yes or no conditions

Tags: c++, while-loop

This is frustrating, look i want the loop to break only if the user inputs 'N' or 'n'.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
char abc;
std::cin >> abc;

while (abc != 'N' || abc != 'n')
{
      std::cout << "hello world\n";
      std::cin >> abc;
}
system("pause");   
return 0;
}
```

These work:

```
while(abc == 'Y' || abc == 'y')
while(abc == 'N')
```

but why?

Comment: Because the character you enter cannot be both `N` and `n` the same time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change

```
while (abc != 'N' || abc != 'n')
```

to

```
while (abc != 'N' && abc != 'n')
```

because
`(abc != 'N' || abc != 'n')` is always TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

Just change "||" to "&&" that will work.

```
while (abc != 'N' && abc != 'n').
```

Answer (score 1):

An application of [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) will help you here:

`!(abc == 'N' || abc == 'n')` is the same as `(abc != 'N' && abc != 'n')`.

The way you have written it will cause the program to loop: `(abc != 'N' || abc != 'n')` is equivalent to `!(abc == 'N' && abc == 'n')` which, of course, is `!(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

The negation of the expression

```
(abc == 'Y' || abc == 'y')
```

can be written as

```
!(abc == 'Y' || abc == 'y')
```

and rewritten as

```
( !( abc == 'Y' ) && !(abc == 'y' ) )
```

and at last as

```
( ( abc != 'Y' ) && (abc != 'y' ) )
```

or simply

```
( abc != 'Y' && abc != 'y' )
```

So the control statement of your loop should be look as

```
while (abc != 'N' && abc != 'n')
```

Moreover logically it would be better to substitute it for do-while loop. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char abc;

   do
   {
      std::cout << "hello world\n";
      std::cin >> abc;
   } while ( abc != 'N' && abc != 'n' );

   system("pause");   

   return 0;
}
```